# -32000 Execution Reverted - Simple AAVE Price Oracle request

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, cpp-ethereum, aave

I'm currently in the early stages of learning solidity and diving into the blockchain world; I do have prior programming experience.

I'm currently stumped on something that seems rather trivial, but is stopping my progress.

I am trying to request the price of the LINK token from AAVE V3. The code I am using is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPriceOracleGetter.sol";
import "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";

contract Flash {

    event print_value(uint256 indexed value1);

    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256) {
        IPoolAddressesProvider provider = IPoolAddressesProvider(address(0xC87385b5E62099f92d490750Fcd6C901a524BBcA));
        address priceOracleAddress = provider.getPriceOracle();
        IPriceOracleGetter priceOracle = IPriceOracleGetter(priceOracleAddress);

        address daiAddress = address(0x6A639d29454287B3cBB632Aa9f93bfB89E3fd18f); 
        uint256 price = priceOracle.getAssetPrice(daiAddress);
        // emit print_value(price);
        return price;
    }

}
```

And the error I am receiving is:

```
call to Flash.getPrice errored: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "code": -32000,
  "message": "execution reverted"
}
```

I am using the ETH Goerli Testnet, with the contract developed with Remix and deployed via "Injected Provider - Metamask".

The addresses I am using have been collected from this doc page:
https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/v3-testnet-addresses

And the RPC details for the testnet are:
RPCUrl = https://goerli.infura.io/v3/9aa3d95b3bc440fa88ea12eaa4456161
ChainID = 5

As with learning any new language, I believe my current hang-up is my inability to properly debug this issue further, or perhaps I'm simply on the wrong chain.

Any help will be much appreciated.

***Update:***

Interestingly, if I switch to the Avalanche Fuji Testnet I am able to get a response, but it is Zero - despite updating the addresses to reflect the Fuji AAVE addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The revert happened because you used an incompatible address to the interface `IPoolAddressesProvider`. In goerli testnet that address should be `0xc4dCB5126a3AfEd129BC3668Ea19285A9f56D15D` as stated in the document. The fix :

```
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256) {
        IPoolAddressesProvider provider = IPoolAddressesProvider(address(0xc4dCB5126a3AfEd129BC3668Ea19285A9f56D15D));
        address priceOracleAddress = provider.getPriceOracle();
        IPriceOracleGetter priceOracle = IPriceOracleGetter(priceOracleAddress);

        // address of link token Goerli
        address daiAddress = address(0x07C725d58437504CA5f814AE406e70E21C5e8e9e); 
        uint256 price = priceOracle.getAssetPrice(daiAddress);
        // emit print_value(price);
        return price;
    }
```

Note that I change the `daiaddress` to something else (`LINK-TestnetMintableERC20-Aave` in the document) to see the price different than 0. Output of `getPrice()` :  `uint256: 3000000000`